# Breeze.js - example of programmatically creating complex documents in metadatastore

Tags: breeze

I'm new to breeze. My data looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Robert',
    hobbies: ['Skiing', 'Surfing'],
    address: {
        street: 'Sample Street',
        city: 'Sampleville',
        country: 'Belgium'
    }
}
```

How do I create this structure in the metadata store programmatically?

Comment: @kadumel by EF, do you mean .Net Entity Framework? If so, no, I'm not - using mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are **not** using Entity Framework.

The Json for the Breeze native metadata format for your model is shown below, with one caveat.  **The 'hobbies' property ( an array of data properties) is not YET supported in Breeze 1.3.4.**  However, it will be supported in our next major release that supports NoSQL datastores like Mongo. I didn't run this thru a json parser, so there may be minor syntax errors, but this should give you the right idea.

```
var jsonMetadata = {
   "metadataVersion":"1.0.4",
   "dataServices":[ {
         "serviceName":"api/Foo/",
         "hasServerMetadata":true,
         "jsonResultsAdapter":"webApi_default",
         "useJsonp":false
      } ],
   "structuralTypes":[ {
         "shortName":"person",
         "namespace":"YourNamespace",
         "dataProperties":[ 
             {  "name":"id",      "dataType":"Int32" },
             {  "name":"name",    "dataType":"String" },
             {  "name: "hobbies", "dataType: "String", isScalar: false },      
             {  "name":"address", "complexTypeName":"address:#YourNamespace" } 
         ] }, {
         "shortName":"address",
         "namespace":"YourNamespace",
         "isComplexType":true,
         "dataProperties":[ 
             {  "name":"street",  "dataType":"String" },
             {  "name":"city",    "dataType":"String" },
             {  "name: "country", "dataType: "String" }    
         } ]
 }
```

You would call this via something like

```
 myEntityManager.metadataStore.importMetadata(jsonMetadata);
```

I've deliberately left out ( taken the defaults) metadata for validations, whether the properties are nullable or not, the maxLength of your string properties (if any) and several other items.  The Breeze documentation contains more info on these.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be `hasServerMetadata:**false**`.  Also, you don't have to quote the hash member names - this is a JavaScript object, not JSON :)  Aside: the verbosity here cries out for a simple DSL. I'm going to hack one together one of these days. Feel free to beat me to it.

Comment: Any hints when the next version (that supports MongoDB) is going to be released? It would be ab-fab if I could reuse my mongo or mongoose schema in breeze, rather than recreating it!

Comment: Also, NoSQL support: graph dbs, like neo4j?

Comment: We will be releasing a server side impl in Node/Express showing how to query Mongo in near term release.  The basic idea should work with most NoSQL dbs but will require an impl for that db.  Of course, the devil is in the details so...

Comment: @JayTraband - brilliant! Do you have an announce list or something I can subscribe to to get updates?

Comment: Is there an example with the json structure that breeze expects. For example, how do we define a unique key property, or how do we set a set validators for a property?